# fullcalendar listview fails

Tags: listview, meteor, fullcalendar

i'm using full calendar in my meteor app. for the responsive design i would like it to switch to list view at smaller screen sizes. changing to list view gives me the following error:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function
TypeError: spec.class is not a constructor
at Calendar_constructor.instantiateView (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:9324)
at renderView (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:9739)
at initialRender (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:9676)
at Calendar_constructor.render (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:9644)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:87)
at Function.each (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:442)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:194)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.fullCalendar (fullcalendar_fullcalendar.js?hash=19f7a11…:66)
at Blaze.TemplateInstance.<anonymous> (calendar.js:90)
at blaze.js?hash=983d07a…:3341
```

the 'agendaWeek' view and others work like a charm. just the list views doesn't.

here is a minimum example. i'm using meteor 1.4.2.3 and i've added only the package fullcalendar:fullcalendar after the meteor create.

main.html

```
<head>
  <title>testFC</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> calendar}}
</body>
```

calendar.html

```
<template name="calendar">
  <div id="events-calendar"></div>
</template>
```

calendar.js

```
let options = {
  firstDay: 1,
  defaultView: 'listWeek',
}
Template.calendar.onRendered( () => {
  $( '#events-calendar' ).fullCalendar(options);
});
```

what could be the problem?
thank you so much for any help
best
s.

Answer (score 0):

[From documentation:](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list_view/intro/)

> Only days with events are displayed.
>   If there are no events during a specific interval of time, the noEventsMessage is displayed.

From your code it looks like you have neither events nor "noEventMessage".